# How to find an image by its href, inside an SVG image, using an XPath query?

Tags: xpath, selenium, svg, raphael

I have a website that contains a "div" element. Inside this "div", an "svg" element exists, which is generated by the JavaScript library "RaphaelJS". Furthermore, I have instructed RaphaelJS to create an image with a particular href inside the SVG element.

In order to do some GUI testing, I would like to test whether the image indeed exists inside the SVG element, with the expected href. Now I would like to write an XPath query (to be used later in Selenium IDE if possible) to do the test. I cannot get seem to get the job done using XPather, or Selenium IDE.

Here's how the website's body looks in short:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
...
<body>
...
<div id="my-container">
<table id="my-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="my-raphael-canvas">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100" height="100">
        <image x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" preserveAspectRatio="none" href="/images/my-icon.jpg"/>
      </svg>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
...
</body>
</html>
```

How should the XPath query look like, if I want to find the "image" element (inside the svg), by its "href"?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`boolean(//xhtml:div[@id = 'my-raphael-canvas']/svg:svg/svg:image[@xlink:href = '/images/my-icon.jpg'])` where you need to ensure that the prefix `xhtml` is bound to the XHTML namespace http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml, the prefix `svg` to the SVG namespace http://www.w3.org/2000/svg, and the prefix `xlink` to the XLink namespace http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink.

Actually your posted sample has the `href` attribute of the SVG `image` element in no namespace but as far as I know SVG defines an `xlink:href` attribute on its `image` element, thus the path I have written uses that.

Comment: I don't believe Selenium has any way for the user to bind XML namespaces, and I don't believe its support for non-native XPath (e.g., for Internet Explorer) supports namespaces at all, even in expanded names.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. So far, I didn't succeed in binding the namespaces in Selenium, but I also didn't succeed doing it in e.g. XPather.

Comment: Is there a way to use the namespace "inline", instead of binding it first? In other words, instead of binding the tag "svg" to [http://www.w3.org/2000/svg](http://www.w3.org/2000/svg), could I use the full URI in my XPath queries?

E.g. I succeeded in finding all elements on the page in the SVG namespace using XPather by doing this: 

    //*[namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg']

Answer (score 0):

I resolved using this expression. in my case worked correctly at selenium + phpunit

```
//div[@id="my-raphael-canvas"]/*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="image" and position()=1]
```